# "Missing" rows on 64x128 LCD after flashing Marlin 1.1.9 onto Monoprice Maker Select v2

Tags: marlin, wanhao, monoprice-maker-select

I've successfully flashed Marlin 1.1.9 onto a Melzi v3.5 board (the stock board for my Monoprice Maker Select v2 (v2.1?, a white-labelled Wanhao i3 Duplicator).

Initially after the flash succeeded the LCD displayed was "garbled".  The right side, in particular, had lots of pixels out of place.  I was able to resolve this by experimenting with some delay variables.  Prior to the flash the LCD was 100 % working; to my knowledge no damage happened while I had the machine apart.

Here's my changes to `Configuration.h` from Marlin 1.1.9, excluding anything to do with X/Y/Z/E, etc (irrelevant stuff).

```
#define MOTHERBOARD BOARD_MELZI
#define SDSUPPORT
#define REVERSE_ENCODER_DIRECTION

//
// LCD for Melzi Card with Graphical LCD
//
#define LCD_FOR_MELZI

// Increase delays to fix garbled LCD
#define ST7920_DELAY_1 DELAY_NS(0)
#define ST7920_DELAY_2 DELAY_NS(100)
#define ST7920_DELAY_3 DELAY_NS(200)
```

The display is much better, however there are about 4x rows of pixels through center of the display running left to right that *mostly* don't display.  There are little sections--perhaps 20x pixels (maybe 3%) that do appear to be displaying.

Here's a photo of the problem:
[image: Marlin 1.1.9 on Maker Select v2 with missing LCD rows]

Are there any other typical culprits?  Based on what I've read it sounds like this is a recent(ish) issue with Marlin, and perhaps would be solved with an older version or a different firmware.

Here's a photo, if you look closely you can see the 'dead' rows, with about 6x pixels work

**PS.**  While troubleshooting I added shielding to the LCD's ribbon cable (foil wrapping the cable, grounded, and wrapped with electrical tape).  It didn't help, but I left it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly unrelated to the firmware?  This happened to me when I tightened the mount screws on the LCD,  after I backed them off a bit it was fine.

Comment: Also,  I was planning on updating the firmware on mine as well, any chance you can supply your full Configuration.h?

Comment: You know, I think you're right!  I haven't opened up the case to try loosening screws, but I pushed gently around the edges of the LCD from the outside and it did seem to improve things.  I'll see if I can dig up `Configuration.h` later today.